# Tattoos in Dexters lab?

Tags: episode-identification, dexters-lab

I seem to remember an episode in Dexter's Lab in which his sister Dee Dee obtained a tattoo on her finger. However, I am having difficulty finding that episode. In which episode did Dee Dee get this Tattoo and why?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the episode [**Decode of Honour**](http://dexterslab.wikia.com/wiki/Decode_of_Honor). Quoting from the wikia's plot description:

> Dee Dee is seen dressed in a camouflage suit and hiding in the bushes. She jumps out and beats up Dexter because those are the tasks on her list. **The next task on her list is to get a tattoo. She goes to the tattoo parlor and asks for a tattoo of a gingerbread man**. Coincidentally, the next task on Dexter's list is to bake gingerbread cookies.

Answer (score 3):

The episode is Season 2, Episode 40: "Decode of Honour".

In the episode, Dee-dee and Dexter both got secret sheets which they had to decode in order to be part of a secret club. The sheets got mixed up, Dee-dee getting Dexter's, and Dexter getting Dee-dee's.  In order to become part of the club, they had to follow the sheet's instructions, which Dee-dee's instructions (meant for Dexter) state that she has to get a tattoo.